# Error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type

Tags: fortran

I having trouble getting rid of this error in the code below. There are 3 functions; dev, norm and clcMatA. The first two functions are called in the third one. But they are not recognized as functions. I have defined them like I do for other functions but I didn't get such errors before.

The errors:

```
Error   1    error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [DEV]   D:\Users\Vahid\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Tst\Tst\Source1.for    66  

Error   2    error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NORM]  D:\Users\Vahid\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Tst\Tst\Source1.for    78
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

The code (in fixed format; .for):

```
      module parameters

      implicit none
      save
      integer :: i,j

      real*8 :: pi = 3.14159265358979323846,KP = 5.e-8, M = 0.5 
      real*8 :: expValPStran, expValDStran, expValVolume

      end module

***********************************      
      program empty

      end program

***********************************      
      function norm(matrix)
      use parameters
      implicit none
      real*8, allocatable, intent(in) :: matrix(:)
      real*8 :: norm,sum
      integer :: dim

      dim = size(matrix,1)

      sum = 0.
      do i=1,dim
        sum = sum + matrix(i)**2
      end do
      norm = sqrt(sum)


      end function      
***********************************      
!      calculates the deviatoric part of the current stress cStress
      function dev(cStress,I_dev,ntens)
      use parameters
      implicit none

      integer :: ntens
      real*8 :: cStress(ntens),I_dev(ntens,ntens)
      real*8 :: dev(ntens)


      dev = matmul(I_dev,cStress)


      end function

***********************************      
      function clcMatA(cStress,D,I_dev,dtime,ndi,ntens)
      use parameters
      implicit none

      integer :: ndi,ntens
      real*8 :: Z(2,ntens), dProductIDev(ntens,ntens), 
     1clcMatA(ntens,ntens),D(ntens,ntens),I_dev(ntens,ntens),
     2cStress(ntens),dProductSigmadev2(ntens,ntens),
     3sigmaDevDyadicProduct(ntens,ntens),identity(ntens,ntens),
     4sigmaDev(ntens),alpha, beta,dtime 


      alpha = expValVolume/(2*expValDStran)
      beta = (6*expValVolume/(pi*expValPStran))**(1/M)*KP
      sigmaDev = dev(cStress,I_dev,ntens)
      dProductIDev = matmul(D,I_dev)

      do i=1,ntens
        do j=1,ntens
            sigmaDevDyadicProduct(i,j)= sigmaDev(j)*sigmaDev(i)
        end do
      end do


      do i=1,ntens
        clcMatA(i,:) = dtime*( (alpha+beta*
     1 norm(sigmaDev)**(1./m-1.))*dProductIDev(i,:) + beta*(1./m-1.)*
     2 norm(sigmaDev)**(1./m-3.) )
      end do


      end function
```

Answer (score 6):

Your source file contains one module, one program and three functions.  You've taken care to *use associate* the module in the functions so that you can use the module's parameters in the functions.  But you've not written any statements, nor structured your code, such that the function `clcMatA` has any knowledge of `norm` or `dev`. Just chucking the definitions of all three functions into the same source file won't provide the information that the compiler needs.

One easy solution would be to include the functions in the module. Insert a line containing the word `contains` after the parameter declarations, then cut and past the code of the functions in between `contains` and `end module`.

While I'm writing:

Why on earth are you using fixed-form source in 2014 ?

It seems strange to `use parameters` in functions where you don't actually use any of the entities defined in the module.

Your function `norm` is a long-winded way of writing

```
norm = sqrt(sum(matrix*matrix))
```

Note that I am using the intrinsic function named `sum` here, I strongly suggest that you don't use `sum` as a variable name.  You won't confuse the compiler, you may confuse yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Including them in a module worked. But I also had to change the name `norm` to something else. I don't know why!
This is a part of an ABAQUS subroutine which accepts by default .for or .obj files. But it can also be written in free-format by some modifications. Actually I have not looked up yet the fundamental differences between the two formats. I will.
Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Or just use the function `norm2` from Fortran 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Your functions `norm` and `dev` are unknown to `clcMatA` as subprograms. You have to tell it what they are with:

```
real*8, external :: dev, norm
```

However, this is not enough, as both function `dev` and `norm` require an explicit interface, because `dev` returns an array-valued result, and `norm` has a dummy argument with the allocatable attribute (read [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101l.doc%2Fxlflr%2Fprogunits_procs_subprogs.htm) page from top to bottom). So, you will either have to write that explicit interface, so your `clcMatA` knows more about them, or put them in a module.

EDIT: fixed wrong link

Comment: Sigh - link has rotted.