# error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type - using function in subroutine

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am using Fortran 90 and the Intel compiler. 
I am very confused using a function in a subroutine. My code is (I deleted everything unimportant):

```
program test
INTEGER     :: seed=5 
REAL        :: nor_ran_number1, nor_ran_number2
CALL Box_Muller_transform(seed,nor_ran_number1,nor_ran_number2)
end program test

double precision function grnd(SEED)
grnd=5
return
end

SUBROUTINE Box_Muller_transform (seed,nor_ran_number1,nor_ran_number2)
implicit none
INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: seed
REAL, INTENT(out)   :: nor_ran_number1, nor_ran_number2

    nor_ran_number1 = grnd(seed)
    nor_ran_number2 = grnd(seed)

end SUBROUTINE Box_Muller_transform
```

The compiler returns:

```
error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit
type.   [GRND]
nor_ran_number1 = grnd(seed)
------------------^
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361763/error-6404-this-name-does-not-have-a-type-and-must-have-an-explicit-type) and understand that the function "grad" is not visible inside "Box_Muller_transform". **However** then I would expect the following code to produce the same error:

```
program test
INTEGER ::a=5, b
call sub(a,b)
write(*,*) b
end program 

SUBROUTINE sub(a,b)
INTEGER, INTENT(in)     ::a
INTEGER, INTENT(out)    ::b
b = fun(a)
end subroutine sub

function fun(a)
INTEGER     :: fun 
INTEGER     :: a
fun         = a*a
end function fun
```

But this is working. 
I would be very happy if someone could point out the difference and explain the simplest way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can resolve a whole host of errors by placing your functions and subroutines inside modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions must have their return value defined. Since you are using `implicit none` in your first example, the type of the return value of `grnd` must be defined explicitly:

```
SUBROUTINE Box_Muller_transform (seed,nor_ran_number1,nor_ran_number2)
implicit none
INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: seed
REAL, INTENT(out)   :: nor_ran_number1, nor_ran_number2
double precision    :: grnd

    nor_ran_number1 = grnd(seed)
    nor_ran_number2 = grnd(seed)

end SUBROUTINE Box_Muller_transform
```

In the second example, you have not specified `implicit none` in `sub`, therefore `fun` is assumed to be of (implicit) type `real`. The compiler seems to silently cast this to integer.